# Bitwise OR of array of bytes

Tags: c#, linq

Given `var a = new byte[] { 15, 4, 7, 81, ..., 4}`. Just need a quick way of getting `a[0] | a[1] | ... | a[a.Length]`.

Comment: Why all the down votes (and not a single comment)? Agreed, it's a question with a simple answer, but there's a million of those on SO. Obviously, the OP's asking for a variant to the standard for loop.

Comment: Probably such questions are asked many times. I could find an answer if I could formulate my question properly, but I was lazy. Maybe that's why.

Comment: Regardless,  if an exact question has been asked many times,  it needs to be flagged as duplicate. Also, it's generally considered polite for down voters to leave a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var a = new byte[] {15, 4, 7, 81, 4};
var result = a.Aggregate(0, (current, bt) => current | bt);
```